# helm global & subchart - call values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've created a helm chart with sub-charts.

The global helm chart contains `values.yaml` and `values-int.yaml` files. as well as all the sub-charts.

this is the structure:

```
- Global-helm-chart:
  - values.yaml
  - values-int.yaml
  - sub-charts:
    - chart-1:
      - values.yaml
      - value-int.yaml
      - templates:
        - configmap.yaml
    - chart-2:
      - values.yaml
      - value-int.yaml
      - templates:
        - configmap.yaml
```

This is the `configmap.yaml` under `chart-1` (chart-2 is the same):

```
{{- $root := .Values -}}
{{ if eq .Values.global.env "int" }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-configuration"
data:
  json: {{ $root.tickets | toJson | quote }}
{{ end }}
```

this is the `values-int.yaml` under `chart-1`:

```
tickets:
  dynamicEvents:
    topics:
    - topic_name: "ai-recommendations-pending-for-review"
      events:
      - name: "PendingForReview"
        parameters:
          subject: "$.insightTypeId"
          group_uid: "customer_care"
```

`helm template .` from the global chart will print out two configMaps, where their values are taken from `values.yaml` and `values-int.yml` of the global chart and **not** as expected which is from `chart-1` and `chart-2`.

I expect helm template from the global-helm-chart to show the `json:`  in configMap with the values of `values-int.yaml` under `chart-1`.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What options exactly are you using to run `helm template`?  I don't think anything will read `sub-charts/chart1/values-int.yaml` unless you explicitly pass that filename in a `-f` option.

Comment: of course, the command I do is: `helm template . -f values-int.yaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm, on its own, doesn't have a notion of per-environment values files the way you're describing it.  If you run

```sh
helm template . -f values-int.yaml
```

that reads `./values-int.yaml` in the current directory, but doesn't look for that file in any other place; in particular it does not try to look for the same-named values file in sub charts.

Instead, you need to fold all of the settings together into a single `values-int.yaml` file wherever you're running the deployment from (it does not need to be in the chart directory *per se*).  That single file [includes settings for all of the sub-charts](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#scope-dependencies-and-values) under top-level keys with the charts' names.

So, with a filesystem layout of:

```
global-helm-chart/
+-- Chart.yaml
+-- values.yaml
+-- values-int.yaml
|
\-- charts/
  +-- chart1/
  | +-- Chart.yaml
  | +-- values.yaml
  | \-- templates/
  |   \-- configmap.yaml
  |
  \-- chart2/ 
    +-- Chart.yaml
    +-- values.yaml
    \-- templates/
      \-- configmap.yaml
```

The top-level `values-int.yaml` would contain:

```yaml
# Helm values for the integration environment.  These override
# settings in values.yaml in this chart and its subcharts.

global:
  env: int

chart1:
  tickets:
    dynamicEvents: { ... }

chart2: { ... }
```

Comment: Your'e the best! Can you also please take a look on this issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019030/helm-concatenate-secretkeyref-into-one-env-var